# How to get HTTPS to work on a website - specifically an Elastic Beanstalk site in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am really struggling to get my basic website (literally just a template without any changes, just running ASP.NET) to work with HTTPS. I am using an Elastic Beanstalk environment to host the site, and the site EC2 virtual machine is behind a load balancer (classic).

I have followed the guide [here](https://medium.com/in-development/tutorial-adding-https-to-a-custom-domain-on-elastic-beanstalk-29a5617b8842) 
And believe I have everything configured correctly, however when I browse to https://www.playground.cloudy-skies.org/ or even the http:// version, I get a HTTP ERROR 503.

I have created an SSL certificate using AWS certificate manager: 
[image]

I have the load balancer in AWS configured like so:
[image]

As per the website documentation, my domain name is pointing to the elastic beanstalk instance, not the load balancer. I've checked the AWS official doco and it says to do pretty much this. Where am I going wrong? if I browse the site with Fiddler active I get:

[image]

Please help? I'm a software developer more than I am a network guy, so I'm doing my best here but I'm struggling and have yet to successfully create a site that uses HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing if you are using Beanstalk your Route 53 will be pointing to your Beanstalk Url only. You can change even force it your Loadblancer also but it doesn't make any change.

As your HTTPS (Port 443) is not working, just check the **Security Group** of **EC2 instance** and **ELB (Elastic Load Balancer)**. Sometimes it happens Security Group block your Port.

So in Your Inbound Rules, (for both ELB and EC2) 443 port should be included

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Karan, thanks for your response! when you say Route 53 will point tobeanstalk url only... that's what the documentation says to do... and it says this is the right step for a load balanced environment (e.g. one with a load balancer included). are you saying it isn't the right step? Not the right configuration? I will check the second part of your answer RE: security groups, but the first part of the answer isn't clear? Also, regarding security groups... I take it I should allow all traffic to the ELB on port 443, then allow traffic to the EC2 on port 443 ONLY from the ELB. Is that right?

Comment: Hey James, For your first doubt about the Route 53. What route 53 do is it maps your subdomain, now it depends upon you whether you want subdomain should be maps to beanstalk url or ELB (both are the same thing).
As you are using Beanstalk then it will be prefer that you should map your subdomain to your beanstalk URL only. 
Mapping subdomain with ELB is for one who are not using Beanstalk and configuring manually.

Hope so this clear your doubt regarding Route 53 . **here Subdomain means "wildcards" in your hosted zone

Comment: Regarding your Second doubt about Security group. yes you are correct, both the security group should allow 443 port  whether its ec2 or ELB.
just check the "Source"- the traffic that can reach your instance

Comment: I'm going to try all these things/ checks and get back to you asap :)

Comment: OMG!!! Success!! After fixing the security groups inbound/outbound I have https!!! https://ibb.co/iNtupo  AWESOME!!! Thanks Karan!